# How to register controllers from the dependencies in Micronaut Framework?

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I have a micrount microservice which i have pushed in my local artifactory service. It contains come basic endpoints which are required for all the other micronaut microservices. How should I register the dependency's controllers to the parent microservices.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to have 2-3 jars (util is optional)

- one for the app itself
- one for the api (only interfaces and dtos)
- one for the util (to provide some rest implementations of the api)

i also suggest, that you have a look on the micronaut declarative client
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation which propably helps you a lot.

So you have two options:

- api and app jar and import for your dependencies only the api jar (you have to take care of the urls) and you probably get in trouble of reimplement the same rest endpoint several times
- api, app and util jar which delegates the rest server and client to your service and allowes you to maintain them together this is difficult if you start mixing frameworks, e.g. a micronaut app is calling a spring boot service or something like that